# have dynamic segments in htaccess as part of a static redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make half of a redirect dynamic while the other is static revelant to the dynamic segment.

```
^img/default/?$ assets/default/themes/ [QSA,L]
```

what I want it to work with is something like

```
/img/default/folder1/folder2/img.png -> /assets/default/themes/folder1/folder2/img.png
```

another use that I want to be able to work is

```
/img/default/folder1/img.png -> /assets/default/themes/folder1/img.png
```

without making a rewrite rule for every single possible url i may have restricting me from making some dynamic references.

Will something like this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^img/default/(.*)$ /assets/default/themes/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```